# How to use SequenceRunner with FlexUnit 4

Tags: apache-flex, flexunit, flexunit4

In the [FlexUnit wiki](http://docs.flexunit.org/index.php?title=Sequences#Sequences_from_Fluint) I've read about the very interesting SequenceRunner that was contributed by the Fluint folks. Now I am trying to run a test that is very similar to the example, however when executing the run() Method of the SequenceRunner instance, I get this exception:

```
    Cannot add asynchronous functionality to methods defined by Test,Before or After that are not marked async
Error: Cannot add asynchronous functionality to methods defined by Test,Before or After that are not marked async
    at org.flexunit.async::AsyncLocator$/getCallableForTest()[C:\Users\dmoor e\Documents\_Production\Flex Unit 4\GIT\FlexUnit4\src\org\flexunit\async\AsyncLocator.as:82]
    at org.fluint.sequence::SequenceWaiter/setupListeners()[C:\Users\dmoore\ Documents\_Production\Flex Unit 4\GIT\FlexUnit4\src\org\fluint\sequence\SequenceWaiter.as:100]
    at org.fluint.sequence::SequenceRunner/continueSequence()[C:\Users\dmoor e\Documents\_Production\Flex Unit 4\GIT\FlexUnit4\src\org\fluint\sequence\SequenceRunner.as:177]
    at org.fluint.sequence::SequenceRunner/run()[C:\Users\dmoore\Documents\_ Production\Flex Unit 4\GIT\FlexUnit4\src\org\fluint\sequence\SequenceRunner.as:124]
```

Has anyone used the SequenceRunner with FlexUnit 4 already. The [Test(async)] annotation is already present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Michael Labriola, who responded to my question in the [Adobe Forum](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/696787?tstart=0) I was finally able to make it running. Note that the documentation of [`SequenceRunner` in the Wiki](http://docs.flexunit.org/index.php?title=Fluint_Sequences) is outdated and partially wrong.

1. Do not inherit from any TestCase class.
2. Skip the asyncHandler for `CREATION_COMPLETE` in the setUp. Rather add a `SequenceWaiter` in the test that waits for the `CREATION_COMPLETE` event of the component
3. The test must be marked as asynchronous test, so add the `[Test(async)]` Metadata to test cases that use `SequenceRunner`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete, very simple example test case class.

```
package test
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    import org.flexunit.asserts.assertEquals;

    import org.fluint.sequence.SequenceRunner;
    import org.fluint.sequence.SequenceWaiter;

    public class test_case
    {
        [Test(async)]
        public function test_function():void
        {
            var counter:Object = { count: 0}
            var sr:SequenceRunner = new SequenceRunner(this);
            sr.addStep(new SequenceWaiter(new TestWaiterTarget(counter), "myEvent", 50000));
            sr.addStep(new SequenceWaiter(new TestWaiterTarget(counter), "myEvent", 5000))
            sr.addAssertHandler(test_function_handler, counter);
            sr.run();
        }

        private function test_function_handler(event:Event, passthroughData:*):void
        {
            assertEquals(passthroughData.count, 2);
        }
    }
}

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

class TestWaiterTarget extends EventDispatcher
{
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(250, 1);

    private var _counter:Object;

    public function TestWaiterTarget(counter)
    {
        _counter = counter;
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timer_timerCompleteHandler);
        timer.start();
    }

    private function timer_timerCompleteHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
    {
        _counter.count++;
        dispatchEvent(new Event("myEvent"));
    }
}
```